# can't find lpthread when cross compile to arm

Tags: android, arm, pthreads, cross-compiling

this is my current problem. Now I am trying to port a x86 based project to android. But this project need pthread library support, and can't pass configuration stage.

Command:

```
./configure --build=${BUILD_SYS} --host=arm-eabi  --prefix=${PREFIX} --disable-rpath --disable-libasprintf --disable-java --disable-native-java --disable-openmp --disable-curses
```

Compiler and compile flags:

```
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYSROOT} -I${SYSROOT}/usr/include -I${PREFIX}/include -I${NDK}/sources/android/support/include -pthread -fPIE -DANDROID -Wno-multichar"
export CXXFLAGS=${CFLAGS}
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYSROOT} -I${SYSROOT}/usr/include -I${PREFIX}/include -I${NDK}/sources/android/support/include -pthread -DANDROID -DNO_XMALLOC -mandroid"
export LIBS="-lc -lgcc -lstdc++ -ldl"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-L${SYSROOT}/usr/lib -L${PREFIX}/lib -L${NDK_TOOLCHAIN}/lib"
```

Error Msg:

```
checking for WIN32... no
checking for Mac... no
checking for Linux... compile in linux
checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... yes
found library uuid
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
configure: error: *** Unable to find pthread library
```

Please help with it: how to attach right flags? **OR** How to cheat to autoconf? **OR** How to cross compile libpthread? **AND** pass the compile finally.

Comment: What specific cross-toolchain (target, version, etc.) are you using? That "arm-eabi" target sounds like you've got a bare-metal-targeted toolchain, which may well be built without pthreads support. For Android you probably want to be using the arm-linux-androideabi toolchain from the NDK.

Comment: @Notlikethat, Hi, I changed host to "arm-linux-androideabi", it still have such a problem. ANDROID_TARGET=armv7-none-linux-androideabi
TOOLCHAIN=arm-linux-androideabi

Answer (score 3):

POSIX threads (pthreads) for Android :

The android libc, bionic, provides built-in support for pthreads, **[so no
additional linking (-lpthreads) is necessary.](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#pthreads)** It does not implement full
POSIX threads functionality and leaves out support for read/write locks,
pthread_cancel(), process-shared mutexes and condition variables as well as
other more advanced features.

So not required to add `-lpthreads` and remove check also.

Comment: I saw this answer and tried it. The thing is that I can't pass autoconf without any flags.

Comment: removed already and didn't work properly,still can't find pthread

Comment: but I need full version